# How to send "response" back to submitted Ajax form?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, response

I am submitting a form using ajax. Then it is processed in PHP, and in the `response` i get the whole PHP/HTML code back. What is the right method to send back a "response" as variables from the PHP?

My JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        "myInput" : $('#myInput').val(), 
    },
    success: function(response) { 
        if(!alert(response)) {
        // do something
        }
    }
});
```

and my PHP simply accepts the posted Input value and manipulates it:

```
if (isset($_POST["myInput"])) {
    // doing something - and I want to send something back
}
```

Comment: If you access the PHP file via its URL (not via AJAX), does it still show the source? Your PHP environment may be unconfigured.

Comment: my index.php file is showing the form itself not the source code. The form is submitted to self, and it does it all good. the response simply shows me the whole source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just echo and exit:

```
if (isset($_POST["myInput"]))
{
    // doing something - and I want to send something back
    exit('Success');
}
```

Then in your JS:

```
success: function(response) { 
    if (response == 'Success') {
       // do something?
    }
}
```

---

For example:

**test.php** *single page html + php post handler*

```
<?php

// Post Handler
if (count($_POST))
{
    // do something with posted data
    echo "You Posted: \r\n";
    print_r($_POST);
    exit();
}

// dummy data outside of the post handler, which will never be sent in response
echo "Test Page";

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.post('test.php', { "hello": "world" }, function(result) {
        alert(result);
    });
});

</script>
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: Thats the issue - I see the `echo` stuff and then below it the entire source code of the page.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I am not sure why the response showed the whole source code after everything. I just added `exit("...")` at the end of the PHP call.

Comment: Yea... as I mentioned before on another person's answer (which is now deleted); if you don't add exit, the the entire output of the script is sent in the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php', // change your url or give conditional statement to print needed code
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        "myInput" : $('#myInput').val(), 
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if(!alert(response)) {
        // do something
        }
    }
});
```